# Adding custom functionality to the events calendar plugin

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-plugin-creation

I have The Events Calendar Plugin installed on my wordpress site. Now, there is an addon that I cannot afford right now (Community Events).

So, I kindly ask, how would I go about recreating just the basic functionality of having users post their own events on the frontend?
I am currently enrolled in a WordPress, plugin and theme development course and my progress is slow. This makes me wonder whether there is some code I can build upon to make my development faster.

Current Skillset: Basic PHP, Intermmediate Wordpress, CSS, HTML, Javascript not ES6, whatever that is. Some SQL (can create tables and write some queries)

What I can do so far:

1. Create a basic plugin and activating it in the admin dashboard
2. Creating Custom post types and Metaboxes
3. Saving my posts
4. Basic understanding of Actions and Filters

What I don't know how to do, yet:

1. Structure a plugin
2. Write good code
3. Clone the community events addon

I just require users to start posting their own events on my website via an interactive frontend and, those events to be refelcted under All Events in The Events Calendar Plugin

Thank you, I appreciate your feedback.

Answer (score 0):

There used to be an alternative plugin a while ago, but it's either not around anymore or obsolete with the more recent versions.

If you want to avoid buying that plugin, I might recommend to either find an alternative events system plugin (other than The Events Calendar) or create two template pages: one for the user to view their events, and one for the user to create a new event or edit their existing events.  Make sure only logged in users can access these pages with something like `if ( ! is_user_logged_in() ) { wp_redirect( wp_login_url() ); exit; }` (redirects to login page).